# How to read and parse the json file and add it into the shell script variable?

Tags: json, linux, shell

I am having the file named loaded.json which contains the below json data.

```
    {
        "name" : "xat",
        "code" : "QpiAc"
    }
    {
        "name" : "gbd",
        "code" : "gDSo3"
    }
    {
        "name" : "mbB",
        "code" : "mg33y"
    }
    {
        "name" : "sbd",
        "code" : "2Vl1w"
    }
```

Form the shell script i need to read and parse the json and add the result to the variable and print it like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
databasename = cat loaded.json | json select '.name'
echo $databasename
```

When i run the above script i am getting error like

```
databasename command not found
json command not found
```

I am new to shell script please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Remove spaces around '=', and wrap command into $(). And you should have json application installed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Replace this,

```
databasename=`cat loaded.json | json select '.name'`
```

or try `jq` command,

```
databasename=`jq '.name' loaded.json`
```

For more information read this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json).

Comment: databasename = `cat loaded.json | json select '.name'` using this command i am getting error as "json: command not found".  if i use underscore insted of json i am getting error as "Error while parsing STDIN in mode 'lax': Unexpected token :". I installed both underscore-cli and also json library.

Comment: @SooryaPrakash replace above code of `json` command with modification to your shellscript first, if not working then try the `jq` command.

Comment: @DrCord link is working perfectly

Answer (score 4):

I can able to get the result using jq command like below

```
databasename=`cat loaded.json | jq '.name'`
```